# Collapse duplicate rows in a dataframe while keeping NAs

Tags: r, row

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Community, Sex, Total Pop, Age, Median
Kodiak,F,NA,NA,3
Kodiak,F,4,Na,NA
Kodiak,F,NA,5,NA
Teru,F,NA,0,NA
Teru,F,0,NA,NA
```

I would like to collapse all of the rows with the common community value name. However, I would also like to keep the NAs (I've done this awhile ago and it made the NAs into 0s which is confusing since 0 has value - the data is census data). My actual dataframe has thousands of rows.

I've tried:

```
library(data.table)
fcensus7 <- fcensus6 %>%
group_by(Community) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

But end up getting this error (it worked before but also made all my NA's into zeroes):

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>       invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have "Na" instead of "NA" for one of your values.  You could try adding `na = c("", "NA", "Na")` to your read_csv function call.

Comment: I checked and it seems its all NA. Could it be something else? I can deal with NAs being there I just need to collapse the rows somehow. Thanks.

Comment: @JulietR - the error definitely suggests you are trying to do `sum()` on `character` data as it gives the same error as `sum("a")`. `Sex` is not numeric for starters and you are trying to sum it.

Comment: If I delete the sex column should it work? EDIT: It worked! such a learning curve to this haha thank you

Comment: or you could just add sex column to the group_by so it will be groub_by(Community, Sex)